# Index with Leftouter join there is always Index scan in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, left-join

I have query joining several tables, the last table is joined with LEFT
JOIN. The last table
has more then million rows and execution plan shows table scan on it. I have
indexed columns
on which the join is made. It is always use index scan but If I replace LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN, index seek is used
used and execution
takes few seconds but with LEFT JOIN there is a table scan , so the
execution
takes several minutes. Does using outer joins turn off indexes? Missed I
something?
What is the reason for such behavior?
Here is the Query

```
Select * 
FROM
```

```
     Subjects                  s
    INNER join       Question  q ON q.SubjectID   = s.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN       Answer    c ON a.QestionID   = q.QuestionID
    Left outer JOIN  Cell      c ON c.Question ID = q.QuestionID
```

Where S.SubjectID =15

There is cluster index on SubjectID in "Subject" table. and there is non-cluster index on questionID in other tables.

Solution:
I try it in other way and now I am index seek on Cell table. Here is the modified query:

```
Select * 
FROM
```

```
     Subjects                  s
    INNER join       Question  q ON q.SubjectID   = s.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN       Answer    c ON a.QestionID   = q.QuestionID
    Left outer JOIN  Cell      c ON c.Question ID = q.QuestionID
                                              AND C.QuestionID > 0
                                              AND C.CellKey > 0
```

Where S.SubjectID =15

This way I did high selectivity on Cell table. :)

Comment: Would you show us the query, and table and index definitions? Which version of sql server do you use?

Comment: Hi automatic, I have edit the question, Please have a look.Thanks

Comment: @user999896 - show your table definitions too please.

Comment: Subjects: Cluster index on SubjectID..... For Question Cluster index on QuestionKey and NonCluster index on QuestionID....For "Answer" table, Cluster index on AnswerKey and non-Cluster index on QuestionID....For "Cell" table Cluster index on CellKey and non-Cluster index on QuestionID

Comment: Hi JNK, I am getting index seek on Subjects and all other table except Cell table becuase as you can see in the where clause I am using SubjectID that gave me filtered values using index see, I have only problem with Cell table. Because ON cell table there is INdex scan

Comment: I asked for the table definitions, too.  Is `QuestionID` an int?  Is it the same in all tables?

Comment: Yes all index columns type is int and it is same in all table.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to simulate the same issue, however there is no table scan instead it was using the clustered index of Cell, at the same time you could try to force the index, you can check the syntax [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/07/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint/) and the issues you may face when forcing an index [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/03/2-features-of-sql-server-you-should-avoid/). Hope this helps.